# Is there a way to disable jsonp in sails.io.js?

Tags: react-native, socket.io, jsonp, sails.io.js

I'm trying to get sails.io.js to work with React Native.
When I try to use this with remote JS debugging switched on, an error pops up saying 'document is not defined', which is fine, because there isn't a document element here. When debugging is off, everything works fine (I'm not completely sure why)

Here's what I've done so far:

After a little bit of digging around, I found that the initial JSONP request is causing the problem, because it is trying to append a script tag to the document.

From their source code, it looks like an initial JSONP request is made here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/blob/89e80e0cf95798c44efb5a60b9607c41b659e6de/sails.io.js#L850

This is made regardless of any options, so I'm pretty sure this isn't configurable, but I'm posting this here just to make sure I didn't miss anything.

In vanilla socketIO, you can passin an option to disable jsonp. Although this works, I'd prefer not using vanilla socketIO because I find the virtual GET requests that sails.io.js lets me do really helpful.

Can anyone help me configure this? If not, I'll consider sending a pull request to the repo in hopes of making this configurable.

Let me know if you need any more information from my end. Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the latest version of sails.io can be made working with RN, I've added this to disable JSONP:

```
io.sails.useCORSRouteToGetCookie = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. There was an issue opened in the sails.io-client github where one of the guys said he removed all the JSONP stuff and cleaned the comments etc. The link to his version was broken, so I made my own.

https://github.com/stokesbga/react-native-sails.io-client